# Python Selenium Testing with unittest - driver error

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

Trying to run a test in python and selenium and I am getting Attribute 
Error: object has no attribute driver'. Where am I going wrong?
The error is below. Trimmed down the code. the issue is with the setup and the first 4 or 5 lines of the test_selenium function

```
        ======================================================================
        ERROR: test_selenium (__main__.Servicenow_IncCreate)
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/firefox_inccreate_cloudv2.py", line 27, in test_selenium
            driver = self.driver
        AttributeError: 'Servicenow_IncCreate' object has no attribute 'driver'

        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Ran 1 test in 0.011s

        FAILED (errors=1)

        The Python code is - >

        from selenium import webdriver
        import time
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
        from datetime import date
        from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
        import unittest

        class Servicenow_IncCreate(unittest.TestCase):
            def setup(self):
                self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

            def test_selenium(self):    
                # 
                today = str(date.today())
                base_url =  "xxx"
                driver = self.driver
                driver.get(base_url)


                driver.switch_to_frame("gsft_main")
                username = driver.find_element_by_id("xxxx")
                username.send_keys("admin")

                password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")
                password.send_keys("xxxx")
                password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


            def teardown(self):
                self.driver.close()         

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, had to use setUp instead of setup...answered